# JavaScript problem adding a class to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, web

**Good day**

I am starting to practice with JavaScript and recently I mounted a simple digital clock using the local time of my pc, I have proposed to add something else to it, to show me the current day in which we are, I want to achieve this with a single tag `<p>` where it contains the days: `Mon - Tue - Wed - Thu - Fri - Sat - Sun`, The idea is to apply a different style to the current day using a `<span>` tag, I do not know if it is the correct way to do it or if there is a more efficient way that consumes less resources and I would like you to help me with this to improve my code .

My current problem boils down to somehow that I am misusing the `Element.classList.add (" class ");` and I can't update the class of my element.

**I attach my code:**

```js
"use strict";

const hour = document.getElementById("hour");
const date = document.getElementById("date");
const days = document.getElementById("day");

let daysString = '<span id="mon"> Mon </span> - <span id="tue"> Tue </span> - <span id="wed"> Wed </span> - ' + 
'<span id="thu">Thu </span> - <span id="fri"> Fri </span> - <span id="sat"> Sat </span> - <span id="sun"> Sun </span>';

const nameMonths = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
                    "August","September","October","November","December"];

days.innerHTML = daysString;

const getTime = ()=>{

    const local = new Date();

    let day = local.getDate(),
        month = local.getMonth(),
        year = local.getFullYear();

    let getTime = local.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
    hour12: true });

    let time = getTime.slice(0, -2);
    let moment = getTime.slice(-2);

    hour.innerHTML = `${time} <span class="ampm">${moment[0]}.${moment[1]}.</span>`;

    date.innerHTML = `${day} / ${nameMonths[month]} / ${year}`;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    let d = local.getDay();
    let finalDays = daysString;
    days.innerHTML = finalDays;
    let currentDay;

    switch(d){

        case 0:
       
        currentDay = document.getElementById("sun");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");

        break;

        case 1:

        currentDay = document.getElementById("mon");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");

        break;

        case 2:

        currentDay = document.getElementById("tue");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");

        break;

        case 3:
 
        currentDay = document.getElementById("wed");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");

        break;

        case 4:

        currentDay = document.getElementById("thu");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");

        break;

        case 5:

        currentDay = document.getElementById("fri");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");
        

        break;

        case 6:
        
        currentDay = document.getElementById("sat");
        currentDay.classList.add("active-day");

        break;

        default:
            
            finalDays = daysString;

    } 

    days.innerHTML = finalDays;

}

getTime();

setInterval(getTime,1000);
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

body{

  background: url(background2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'lato';

}

.container-clock{

  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  

}

.container-clock h1{

  font-size: 12rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #409CFA;

}

.dates{

  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #409CFA;

}

.days{

  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  text-shadow: 0 0 8px #409CFA;

}

.active-day{

  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #409CFA;
  font-size: 2rem;

}

.ampm{

  font-size: 5rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Digital clock</title>
</head>
<body ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">

    <div class="container-clock">

        <h1 id="hour">00:00:00</h1>
        <p id="date" class="dates">date</p>
        <br><br>
        <p id="day" class="days">day-day-day-day-day-day-day</p>

    </div>
    
    <script src="clock.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can not get the desired effect since I can not add the desired class to the elements, I would appreciate whoever tells me that I am doing wrong.

In the same way, I would appreciate any advice and / or ideas on how to improve this code, for example, I understand that it would be better to use `if / else` than`switch ()`since it consumes less resources.

I have also realized that I am not deleting the active day class when the day ends at 23:59, in the same way at the moment there is no class to replace or delete until I solve my problem.

**Thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help me!**

Comment: I get "*ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fecha*".

Comment: An efficient answer is given below by @Ofek. By the way, the problem with your code is, you are setting the **InnerHTML** of "days" with the list of spans. Instead, try using `appendChild()` for every span, then the addition of class using `switch` will have no problem.

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's unclear what exact problem you are asking us to solve here. It looks more like a request to review your code. Please narrow down the problem and provide a useful title. Questions like this are not going to be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a problem in line 31:

```
fecha.innerHTML = `${day} / ${nameMonths[month]} / ${year}`;
```

you didn't defined the varible fecha

the main problem you showed here happening because you copy the 'innerHTML' of day, then change things inside day, and paste back the innerHTML you copied.

the solution is just removing the lines:

```
let finalDays = daysString;
days.innerHTML = finalDays;
```

and the line at the end:

```
days.innerHTML = finalDays;
```

a thing I noticed is that you are changing the html of days at the beginning of the java script, you don't need to do that if you can just write this in the html

i wrote a simplification for the switch case you wrote:

```
let d = local.getDay();

let currentDay = days.children[(d + 6) % 7];
let lastDay = days.children[(d + 5) % 7];

currentDay.className = "active-day";
lastDay.className = "inactive-day";
```

(i added 6 instead of removing 1 because (0 - 1) % 7 is -1 and not 6)

instead of

```
const getTime = ()=>{
```

you can just write

```
function getTime() {
```

(its more standard)

the final code:

```js
"use strict";

const hour = document.getElementById("hour");
const date = document.getElementById("date");
const days = document.getElementById("day");

const nameMonths = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
                    "August","September","October","November","December"];


function getTime() {

    const local = new Date();

    let day = local.getDate(),
        month = local.getMonth(),
        year = local.getFullYear();

    let getTime = local.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
    hour12: true });

    let time = getTime.slice(0, -2);
    let moment = getTime.slice(-2);

    hour.innerHTML = `${time} <span class="ampm">${moment[0]}.${moment[1]}.</span>`;

    //fecha.innerHTML = `${day} / ${nameMonths[month]} / ${year}`;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    let d = local.getDay();

    let currentDay = days.children[(d + 6) % 7];
    let lastDay = days.children[(d + 5) % 7];

    currentDay.className = "active-day";
    lastDay.className = "inactive-day";

}

getTime();

setInterval(getTime,1000);
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

body{

  background: url(background2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'lato';

}

.container-clock{

  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  

}

.container-clock h1{

  font-size: 12rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #409CFA;

}

.active-day {
  color: aqua;
}

.inactive-day {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Digital clock</title>
</head>
<body ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">

    <div class="container-clock">

        <h1 id="hour">00:00:00</h1>
        <p id="date" class="dates">date</p>
        <br><br>
        <p id="day" class="days">
            <span class="inactive-day">Mon</span>-
            <span class="inactive-day">Tue</span>-
            <span class="inactive-day">Wed</span>-
            <span class="inactive-day">Thu</span>-
            <span class="inactive-day">Fri</span>-
            <span class="inactive-day">Sat</span>-
            <span class="inactive-day">Sun</span>
        </p>

    </div>
    
    <script src="clock.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

btw, you don't need to worry about consuming less resources because javascript is not for making thing that need lot of resources

(sorry if my english is bad, its not my native language)

Comment: why date is not showing current day and date?

Comment: You mean the title 'date'? below the title 'date' I see the correct day

Comment: I see "date" text, how about if it shows the current date and day?

Comment: under the text date, you can see the current day in cyan

Comment: I meant about "date", why "date" text is there instead of current date like 06-July-2021 or something like that.

Comment: I guess he didn't implement this

Comment: ok, I thought its a bug.

Comment: You should dump 95% of the HTML and script to just show the part that needs fixing.

Comment: @Ofek forgive my English because it is not my native language either, the variable "fecha" was defined above as "date", my mistake, I happened to translate it, I also thought that the more JS and less HTML it was better, your solution with "element .children "It has worked correctly for me, I have already applied it and I am analyzing to better understand its operation and apply it in other things and I have obtained the desired result, I thank you for that solution and all the advice you have given me, thank you very much .

Comment: You said you are analyzing, If you have questions feel free to ask